# Permission Error Running Shell Command from Symphony Process as WWW-DATA

Tags: php, linux, laravel, shell, symfony

I am trying to run a shell command from a symphony process. This command uses headless chrome to navigate to a route on my server and generate a pdf.

This command works when i run it from my temrinal (as root).

When i run this command from my laravel app (executed by www-data) i get what i believe to be are permission errors because the exact same command works from the CLI.

I obviously dont want to add www-data to the root group, how can i find out where i need to provide permissions so i can run the command from www-data?

Code

```
  $process = new Process(["/usr/bin/google-chrome", escapeshellarg("--no-sandbox"),escapeshellarg("--headless"),escapeshellarg("--disable-gpu"),escapeshellarg("--print-to-pdf="),escapeshellarg("/home/test/my.pdf"),escapeshellarg("google.com")]);

    try {

        $process->mustRun();

        Log::debug("Such PDF");

    } catch (ProcessFailedException $exception) {

        Log::debug($exception->getMessage());

    }
```

And the error

```
[2022-03-13 23:54:38] local.DEBUG: The command "'/usr/bin/google-chrome' ''\''--no-sandbox'\''' ''\''--headless'\''' ''\''--disable-gpu'\''' ''\''--print-to-pdf='\''' ''\''/home/test/my.pdf'\''' ''\''google.com'\'''" failed.

Exit Code: 1(General error)

Working directory: /var/www/app/public

Output:
================


Error Output:
================
[31396:31396:0313/235438.397944:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(234)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[31396:31396:0313/235438.399288:ERROR:env.cc(225)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
```

Comment: What is permission set on `/usr/bin/google-chrome` and who is owner and group of that file? `ls -la /usr/bin/google-chrome` to check.

Comment: @Tpojka both are root/root, should i change change to wwwdata?

Comment: Try with adding `sudo chmod o+x /usr/bin/google-chrome` so other (like www-data or any other OS user) could execute that file.

Answer (score 0):

I think your X-SERVER is not configured properly. You should set the $DISPLAY variable. Try to set DISPLAY in your .bashrc file.

```
export DISPLAY="localhost:0"
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

Comment: Do i appened these to by .bashrc file ? I dont see them anywhere. Also, i am doing this through SSH

Comment: open the file with "nano ~/.bashrc", then append the two lines and save the file. Check that the lines are there with "cat ~/.bashrc".